# scalafmt download error while using nexus

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-plugin, scalafmt

I want to use Scalafmt in corporate network ( on a windows machine) using Nexus. I get below error if i run `scalafmt`

```
[error] failed to resolve Scalafmt version '2.4.6': X:\ProjectA\.scalafmt.conf
[error] (Compile / scalafmt) failed to resolve Scalafmt version '2.6.4': X:\ProjectA\.scalafmt.conf
[error] Total time: 87 s (01:27), completed 10-Jan-2023 10:56:22
```

I already have `COURSIER_REPOSITORIES` environment variable.

- SBT Version: 1.6.2
- scalafmt plugin: 2.2.1
- version in .scalafmt: 2.4.6

Am I missing any resolver or any setting?

Comment: Isn't it 2.4.6 instead of 2.6.4? https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.scalameta/sbt-scalafmt  https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/installation.html#sbt

Comment: @DmytroMitin you are right, it is 2.4.6. Multiple typos( i was testing with  same 2.4.6 version) .

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure there is scalafmt 2.4.6 in your corporate Nexus. Also there might be scalafmt but of older version.

Comment: There is already 2.4.6 version in corporate nexus.